# Can't find jar files in spring framework 4.0.6?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

Today, i donwloaded `Spring Framework 4.0.6` latest version but unable to locate the jar files, and i donwloaded eclipse plugin for spring too, here i find nothing and looking for a way to include these jar files into eclipse, here is a [pic](http://postimg.org/image/xnkgewd0f/).

Some tutorials website refers that it contains into `lib folder` but i can't see it, please help!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have a number of hurdles to overcome:

- How to use Eclipse
- How to manage Java dependencies
- How to use Spring

I'm not sure what your level of experience is, but you may wish to consider using [Spring Tool Suite](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQjBAwAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fspring.io%2Ftools%2Fsts%2Fall&ei=4AHbU_TeKIXh8AXV9IGADQ&usg=AFQjCNEF_QuOHFCC_CoE7OE0l8L8BiWVqA&sig2=8qoXweeWgHdO4w-x6mQROg&bvm=bv.72197243,d.aWw) as your IDE - it's based on Eclipse with additonal plugins to aid Spring development.

I also urge you to use Maven or Gradle to manage your dependencies. The Spring documentation provides the configuration for adding the dependencies in both. I'd recommend Maven as a starting point as it is easy to use with little knowledge and is well suited to small, standard projects. Gradle is worth a look once you are comfortable with Maven.

Work though the [Guides](http://spring.io/guides) - I'd start with 'Building Java Projects with Maven'.

**Edit**

[Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) is a dependency management and build tool that favours convention over configuration. Dependency management is powerful in that you can declare a dependency on Spring Core, for example, and it will download all the related dependencies for you.

[Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) performs similar functions to Maven but also provides the ability to use scripting. Gradle is seen by many as Maven's predecessor and has been adopted by Spring over Maven.

In my opinion Maven is easier for you at this stage.

Comment: Yes, I'm completly new `JAVA EE WORLD` but i'm good familiar with core JAVA only, and dont know about the dependencies, by the What's the use of here Grandle and Maven?